# Any way to get random places from Facebook Search Places API?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, pagination, offset

I have been working with the Places Search API in Facebook's API Explorer. Currently I am returning results limited to 20 per page, with countless pages. For my application I would like to retrieve 20 random places.

I have tried using the offset pagination to specify a random offset, but the offset parameter doesn't seem to be working, as it is returning the same ordered results. I could just iterate through each page using cursor pagination, but this would return every result and seems illogical. Any ideas on how to this can be done?

My current call: https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/search?pretty=0&fields=name%2Ccheckins&type=place&center=40.7304%2C-73.9921&categories=[%22FOOD_BEVERAGE%22]&distance=10000&limit=20

Comment: _“but the offset parameter doesn't seem to be working”_ - this endpoint appears to be using cursor-based pagination, so you need the values of the before/after parameters the API provides in response to your request. _“but this would return every result and seems illogical”_ - well, they probably didn’t have apps using _random_ places in mind as a “logical” use case either :-) If you only need this for specific coordinates and categories, and not depending on any actual user input, I guess your best bet is to request a large enough bunch, cache it on your end, and randomly select from that.

Comment: I decided to go this route, as it does seem impossible to do this using just an API call. Using a python script to get 200 places, shuffling the results and slicing the array seems to do the job well. Thanks for looking into it